# Pandas AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'

Tags: python, pandas

this is my code:

```
DF['CustomerId'] = DF['CustomerId'].apply(str)
print(DF.dtypes)
for index, row in merged.iterrows():
    DF = DF.loc[(DF['CustomerId'] == str(row['CustomerId'])), 'CustomerId'] = row['code']
```

My goal is to do this:
if `DF['CustomerId']` is equal to `row['CustomerId']` then change value of `DF['CustomerId']` to `row['CustomerId']`
else leave as it is.

`row['CustomerId']` and `DF['CustomerId']` should be string. I know that `loc` works not with string, but how can I do this with string type ?
thanks

Comment: Are you sure about your "goal"?

Comment: Hi, Yes. just want to update customerId as we change of reference method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach without looping by merging the 2 dataframes on the common `CustomerId` column using [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then update the `CustomerID` column with the `code` column originated from the 'merged' datraframe with [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), as follows:

```
df_out = DF.merge(merged, on='CustomerId', how='left')
df_out['CustomerId'].update(df_out['code'])
```

### Demo

**Data Preparation:**

```
data = {'CustomerId': ['11111', '22222', '33333', '44444'],
 'CustomerInfo': ['Albert', 'Betty', 'Charles', 'Dicky']}
DF = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(DF)

  CustomerId CustomerInfo
0      11111       Albert
1      22222        Betty
2      33333      Charles
3      44444        Dicky


data = {'CustomerId': ['11111', '22222', '44444'],
 'code': ['A1011111', 'A1022222', 'A1044444']}
merged = pd.DataFrame(data) 

print(merged)


  CustomerId      code
0      11111  A1011111
1      22222  A1022222
2      44444  A1044444
```

**Run New Code**

```
# ensure the CustomerId column are strings as you did
DF['CustomerId'] = DF['CustomerId'].astype(str) 
merged['CustomerId'] = merged['CustomerId'].astype(str) 

df_out = DF.merge(merged, on='CustomerId', how='left')


print(df_out)

  CustomerId CustomerInfo      code
0      11111       Albert  A1011111
1      22222        Betty  A1022222
2      33333      Charles       NaN
3      44444        Dicky  A1044444

df_out['CustomerId'].update(df_out['code'])

print(df_out)

# `CustomerId` column updated as required if there are corresponding entries in dataframe `merged`

  CustomerId CustomerInfo      code
0   A1011111       Albert  A1011111
1   A1022222        Betty  A1022222
2      33333      Charles       NaN
3   A1044444        Dicky  A1044444
```